# Bash Date WakeUp

Tags: bash, date

Since months I used this command in a script on my NAS:

```
sudo rtcwake -m disk -t  "$(date -d 'tomorrow  02:00:00' '+%s')"
```

Today I got an error.

My test results:

```
root@omvnas:~# date -d 'tomorrow  02:00:00' '+%s'
date: ungültiges Datum „tomorrow  02:00:00“
root@omvnas:~# date -d '+1 day 3:00'
Mo 30. Mär 03:00:00 CEST 2020
root@omvnas:~# date -d '+1 day 2:00'
date: ungültiges Datum „+1 day 2:00“
root@omvnas:~# date -d '+1 day 1:00'
Mo 30. Mär 01:00:00 CEST 2020
```

"ungültiges Datum" is German for "invalid date".

Why is this happening ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time Just guessing

Comment: BTW if you use the `-u` option, `date` will use the `UTC` timezone, which won't thereby be impacted by the daylight-saving-time change (which occurs typically between `01:59:59` and `03:00:00`)

Comment: Thanks for your Help. I guess my new favorite backup-start-time is 3:00 now.

Comment: debian 9.11 with omv4

Answer (score 2):

This issue is indeed related to the [daylight saving time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time), but this does not appear to be a bug of the `date` program, rather a "feature": all the commands below raise an error, because the specified time does not exist in the local timezone (which directly goes from `01:59:59` to `03:00:00`).

```
$ date -d '02:00:00'
date: invalid date ‘02:00:00’
$ date -d '02:30:00'
date: invalid date ‘02:30:00’
$ date -d '+1 day 02:30:00'
date: invalid date ‘+1 day 02:30:00’
$ date -d '+2 day 02:30:00'
date: invalid date ‘+2 day 02:30:00’
```

and the last two commands above certainly raise an error because the `date` program attempts to increment the number of days *after* resolving the specified time, which is indeed invalid.

As I mentioned in my comment, a reliable way to workaround this issue could be to rely on the `UTC` timezone (option [`--utc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html)):

```
$ date -d 'today 01:59:59' -R
Sun, 29 Mar 2020 01:59:59 +0100
$ date -d 'today 01:59:59' '+%s'
1585443599
$ date -d 'today 02:00:00' '+%s'
date: invalid date ‘today 02:00:00’
$ date -d 'today 03:00:00' '+%s'
1585443600
$ date -u -d 'today 01:00:00' '+%s'  # OK thanks to option -u
1585443600
```

Comment: i am pretty sure 2:00 to 3:00 exist in my local timezone. :D

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in `date` / `tzdata` which is related to [daylight saving time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

Here is a related bug report:
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=819342

It's is still reproducible with a current Debian Sid.

Your best bet for now, is to use a time which is not affected by DST (e.g 03:00:00).